# Convert select count() MySQL query to Codeigniter query

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

This is my query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `job_progress` WHERE status='Runing'
```

**Help Me**: I know SQL command please help me for Codeigniter command.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*You can use `count_all_results` to count data with `where` conditions*

Simply run below query:

```
$this->db->where('status','Runing');
return $this->db->count_all_results('job_progress');
```

In model add the below method to count all records

```
public function get_count()
{
   $this->db->where('status','Runing');
   return $this->db->count_all_results('job_progress');
}
```

In controller :

*make sure you have loaded your model containing this method*

```
$count = $this->model_name->get_count();
echo $count;
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `$this->db->select('count(*)')->from('job_progress')->where('status','Running')->get()->row();`

To know how to build codeigniter queries, read codeigniter query builder documentation : [Click here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)